# Изменения свойств при окончании изменения в ячейке DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть класс

```
public class ClassA: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
  }
  string m_Text="";
  public string Text
  {
    get { return m_Text; }
    set
    {
      m_Text = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
    }
  }
}
```

Есть `Grid`, элементами которого являются члены класса `ClassA`

```
<Grid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Text}">
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</Grid>
```

Всё отрабатывает на ура, только вот в чём проблема, `m_Text=value` отрабатывает только при потере/изменении выбранной строки. т.е. Если я изменил данные, нажал ентер, но строчку выделенную не поменял, то и Text в экземпляре класса не изменился. Как исправить этот недочёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` в Binding.

> Если я изменил данные, нажал ентер, но строчку выделенную не поменял, то и Text в экземпляре класса не изменился

так как по умолчанию стоит `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`, т.е. изменения происходят при потере фокуса, как и в вашем случае.

```
<Grid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</Grid>
```